# How do you sort an Observable<Item[]> in Angular 6 with rxjs 6?

Tags: typescript, angular6, rxjs6

I just want to sort data on an observable of my class type 'Category'.  So Observable < Category[] > I want to sort.

So I upgraded to Angular6 and rxjs6 with it.  One issue that is probably simple Typescript that I do know is how do I just do a 'sort' operation like:

```
sort((x,y) => x.description < y.description ? -1 : 1)
```

Inside of the new Angular6?  I used to do this in 5

```
var response = this.http.get<Category[]>(this.endpoint);
        .map((result: Response) => this.alphabetize(result));


alphabetize = (result: Response) => this.Categories = result.json()
.sort((x,y) => x.description < y.description ? -1 : 1)
```

And it worked fine.  Now in the HttpCLIENTModule and HttpClient that Angular wants you to use it is simpler:

```
var data = this.http.get<Category[]>(this.endpoint);
```

I just put the magic <(object)> before my endpoint and it does it for me.  Cool.  But I am not seeing how you get inside the object easily to sort from it with Source, Pipe, from, of.  I know it is probably something simple I just don't know the syntax for.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It is:

```
this.http.get<Category[]>(this.endpoint).pipe(
  map(results => results.sort(...))
);
```

Or since `sort` modifies existing array, it's more semantically correct to provide side effects in `do`/`tap`:

```
this.http.get<Category[]>(this.endpoint).pipe(
  tap(results => {
    results.sort()
  })
);
```

Comment: They should work similarly in this case. But glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For angular12 when I try this solution it give me this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property ‘sort’ of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property ‘sort’ of undefined
```

To fix this error. I used pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
  name: 'sortByDate'
})
export class SortByDatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    value = [...value]; // fixed to second error

    return value.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date1).getTime() - new Date(a.date1).getTime());

  }

}
```

At this time it gives this.

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property ‘0’ of object ‘[object Array]’ Error ?
```

I already explain that in code(above)  but you can check [here](https://flutterq.com/typeerror-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-0-of-object-object-array/#:%7E:text=Array%5D%27%20Error%3F-,To%20Solve%20TypeError%3A%20Cannot%20assign%20to%20read%20only%20property%20%270,Like%20using%20a%20spread%20operator.&text=Then%20after%20sorting%20you%20could%20assign%20it%20back%20to%20the%20taskList%20field.) if it doesnt solve the error.

Here is the html code

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data$ | async | sortByDate">
//your code goes here
</div>
```